# why multiprocessing pool taking more time when increasing the process?

Tags: python

I want to append a list named result with result of 2 functions named calculation and calculation2. Why only results of calculation2 are there. I would want results of both.

```
import multiprocessing
def calculation(numbers,result):
    for index,number in enumerate(numbers):
        result[index] = number*number
    # print('inside_multiprocessing::',result)

def calculation2(numbers,result):
    for index,number in enumerate(numbers):
        result[index] = number*number*number
    # print('inside_multiprocessing::',result)

if __name__=='__main__':
    result = multiprocessing.Array('i',50)
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=calculation,args=([1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,9],result))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=calculation2,args=([1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,9],result))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print('outside_multiprocessing::',result[:])
```

Comment: you save values at the same positions of `result` in BOTH methods, one overwrite the other so

Comment: Share the exact output and the exact expected output

Comment: I may need a coffee but I cannot see how the title, the text of the question and the code are related...

Comment: Maybe your intention was to append to the array. What you're actually doing is updating specific indexes. Therefore the final result will be indeterminate (in principle). In your particular case, *calculation()* probably runs and terminates before *calculation2()* starts. Therefore, you're getting the results from the most recently executed sub-process

Answer (score 0):

Your array needs to be at least twice as big as the number of items in your list. You may find this approach useful:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Array


def calculation(numbers, result):
    for index, number in enumerate(numbers):
        result[index] = number*number


def calculation2(numbers, result):
    for index, number in enumerate(numbers, len(numbers)):
        result[index] = number*number*number


if __name__ == '__main__':
    nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    result = Array('i', len(nums)*2)
    p = []
    for t in [calculation, calculation2]:
        p.append(Process(target=t, args=(nums, result)))
        p[-1].start()
    for p_ in p:
        p_.join()

    print(result[:])
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729, 1000]
```